# Convert jpeg image to thumbnail image in Qt

Tags: qt, qimage, qpixmap, qbytearray, qicon

A `QImage` needs to be finally shown as a thumbnail image in a `QLabel`. In between it's serialized in `QByteArray` and sent over the network. So, can we convert the `QImage` to `QByteArray` for thumbnail? Basically I want to avoid the `QImage::scale()` method as it's quite CPU consuming.
Like `QImage` converted to a `QByteArray` which will hold data for thumbnail images.

Comment: What does it help to store contents of `QImage` in a `QByteArray` concerning scaling? Why do you want to avoid `QImage::scale()`? Of course, it might be CPU consuming though this depends strongly on the image size. Please, consider that default `transformMode` of [`QImage::scaled()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#scaled) is [`Qt::FastTransformation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TransformationMode-enum) which is probably hard to beat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this case you cannot avoid QImage::scale. Why do you want?
This is the answer to your question how to save QImage to QByteArray.

```
        QFile file(imagePath);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            QByteArray bytes;
            QImage img;
            img = img.fromData(file.readAll());
            img = img.scaled(200, 100, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
            SetLabelImage(img);
            QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
            img.save(&buffer, "PNG");
        }
```

Comment: Yeah...is there a way to do the scaling in Qbuffer  of QByteArray, rather than doing scaling with QImage?

Comment: Why?  You seem to think that will provide some performance advantage but you haven't stated why. How large are the images in question?

Comment: Image sizes are not much around 500kb, but there are many images..like 10K+ , so mostly concerned about processing and slowing down the process by image.scale(x,y).